# How to obtain wifi security type of current wifi network in android

Tags: java, android, security, android-wifi

Is there a way to obtain the wifi security type of the network that the device is currently connected. I know that wifi security could be obtained by scanning network. but is it possible without scanning so that I can get it for the current wifi network??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the ScanResult.capabilities to see the security type of a network.
You can use this without actually scanning for networks, using something like:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> networkList = wifi.getScanResults();
if (networkList != null) {
    for (ScanResult network : networkList)
    {
        String Capabilities =  network.capabilities;        
        Log.w (TAG, network.SSID + " capabilities : " + Capabilities);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know that, i mean without scanning!